# Selenium 3 - Add Port for Node when run Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-grid, selenium3

At the moment, I am configuring Hub and Nodes for a Selenium 3 Grid setup.

- Hub : 
  **Start Selenium Hub**
  `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -role hub`;
- Node : 
  **Start Selenium node**
  `java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=c:\ws\IEDriverServer.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.12.110:4444/grid/register`

**Question:** I want to have the Node connecting to my Hub through a predefined port (`-port 5555`). How should I configure the port property for the Node?

**!!! Note:** with Selenium 2, I successfully configured the node with port 5555: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver -hub http://10.0.12.110:4444/grid/register -port 5555 -browser  "browserName=chrome,version=ANY,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=c:\WS\chromedriver.exe -browser`

However, property `-port 5555` doesn't seem to work/have effect in Selenium 3.

How can I make it work?

Comment: I am able to connect with the node using the default port 5555 and no need to add any property.

Comment: Check if the port already is in use. If so try with different port

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the error message? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create node-config.json file and store port parameter there. Format of config file:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
        }
    ],
    "port": 5555,
}
```

Then start your node with

```
java -jar /path_to_driver/serve.jar -role node -hub HUB_ADDRESS -nodeConfig /path_to_node_config/node-config.json
```

More config options you can find [HERE](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)
Detailed about configuration in [Selenium 3](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-json)